# Linux command line: run mon nice and C exectuable together

Tags: linux, command-line, terminal, nice

I'm trying to run ./a.out, but monitored (using mon) and nice'd to highest priority.

Here are the commands separately:

```
nice -n -20 /home/pi/a.out   //works fine

mon /home/pi/a.out   //works fine

mon nice -n -20 /home/pi/a.out   //doesn't work!
```

I get an "unrecognized flag -n" error...

How to do this?

Many thanks in advance,

Comment: It seems that `mon` considers `-n` as it's own option. I haven't worked with mon, but try putting the command after mon in `''`

Comment: @hnik Yes, you're right. I believe mon thinks the -n is for it. Thanks for that. I'll try the quotes. I'll also try back-ticks.

Comment: Another variation that will probably work is `nice -n -20 mon /home/pi/a.out`.  In case it isn’t obvious, this differs in effect from what you are trying in that this command will run the `mon` program at high priority (in addition to your `a.out`), whereas your command runs `mon` at default priority, while elevating `a.out`.